# Script to check unique constraints and create one

Tags: sql, sql-server

T-SQL script required to check, if a specified column has any unique constraints/indexes and create unique index if it doesn't exist.

Comment: What have you tried? Where did you get stuck?

Comment: i was able to find solution. thank you for asking.

Comment: @DaleK you can see the solution that I found and wrote - posted as answer for this ticket.

Comment: FYI in future when you post a question give more detail and show what research you have done and what you have tried.

Comment: thanks for your feedback

Answer (score 1):

[This link](https://www.source-code.biz/snippets/mssql/2.htm) gave me an idea for writing T-SQL.

Sharing below script to check if any UNIQUE indexes exist for a specified column

```
--Check if there are any unique indexes for a specified column.
IF NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT SC.name
    FROM sys.indexes SI
    JOIN sys.index_columns SIC 
        ON SIC.object_id = SI.object_id
        AND SIC.index_id = SI.index_id
    JOIN sys.columns SC 
        ON SC.object_id = SIC.object_id
        AND SC.column_id = SIC.column_id
    WHERE 
        SI.object_id = OBJECT_ID('zztablename')
        AND SI.is_unique_constraint = 1
        AND SC.name = 'zzid' 
)
BEGIN 
    -- Check for a specific index name
    IF NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT 1
        FROM sys.objects
        WHERE 
            object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'zzUniqueIndexName')
            AND TYPE IN (N'UQ')
        ) 
    BEGIN
        ALTER TABLE zztablename ADD CONSTRAINT zzUniqueIndexName UNIQUE (zzid);
    END
END
```